# BeautifulSoup get text outside given elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this html chunk as follows:

```
html = 
'''
<div class="details">Mol Cell Biol. 
  <span class="citation-publication-date">2001 Dec; </span>
  21(24): 8471–8482.
  <span class="doi">doi: 10.1128/MCB.21.24.8471-8482.2001</span>
</div>
'''
```

I would like to get only text outside of `<span>` which are `Mol Cell Biol.` and `21(24): 8471–8482.` using BeautifulSoup. If I do `s.text`, it will give all text including text in `<span>` tag:

```
s = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
s.text
```

It would be even better if I can grab `Mol Cell Biol.` and `21(24): 8471–8482.` separately in this given case i.e. returning list of `["Mol Cell Biol.", "21(24): 8471–8482."]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the text and only include text that doesn't have the `span` tag

```
[text for text in s.find_all(text=True) if text.parent.name != "span"]
```

Outputs:

```
[u'Mol Cell Biol. ', u'21(24): 8471\u20138482.']
```

Answer (score 1):

*There is a simpler way* - use `find_all(text=True)` but also with `recursive=False` flag which would bring you the top-level texts only:

```
details = s.select_one(".details")
data = details.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)
```

Demo (with some post-processing):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> html = '''
... <div class="details">Mol Cell Biol.
...   <span class="citation-publication-date">2001 Dec; </span>
...   21(24): 8471–8482.
...   <span class="doi">doi: 10.1128/MCB.21.24.8471-8482.2001</span>
... </div>
... '''
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
>>> 
>>> details = soup.select_one(".details")
>>> data = details.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)
>>> data = [item.strip() for item in data]
>>> data = [item for item in data if item]
>>> print(data)
[u'Mol Cell Biol.', u'21(24): 8471\u20138482.']
```